# Cannot wire up Azure Scaleset to Automation DSC using powershell cmdlets

Tags: azure, powershell, dsc, azure-automation

I'm trying to wire up Scaleset VMs to the Azure Automation DSC server using the DSC extension.  This is not exposed via the Portal, but from [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/dsc-template#example-using-referenced-azure-automation-registration-values) it seems that it should be possible though templates and powershell cmd line.

I have the boiled things down to the following snippet (with sensitive vars masked):

```
$settings = @{
    configurationArguments = @{
        registrationUrl = "https://ne-agentservice-prod-1.azure-automation.net/accounts/xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
    }
}    
$protectedSettings = @{
    configurationArguments = @{
        registrationKey = @{
            userName = "NOT_USED"
            password = "/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=="
        } 
    } 
}

Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -VMScaleSetName $VmSsName | 
    Add-AzureRmVmssExtension -Name "DSC" -Publisher "Microsoft.Powershell" -Type "DSC" -TypeHandlerVersion "2.24" -Setting $settings -ProtectedSetting $protectedSettings |
    Update-AzureRmVmss
```

In the portal, the extension is listed.  However nothing is happening: I neither see any VMs listed in the Automation DSC "Nodes" list, nor do I see an DSC activity on the scaleset VMs - the event viewer for DSC is empty; the "c:\WindowsAzure\Logs" folder has nothing related to DSC.

I'm at wits-end as I feel tantalizingly close to getting this working, but am getting no feedback as to what is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get the `Add-AzureRmVmssExtension` as part of a `New-AzureRmVmss` powershell pipeline flow.  I needed to make two changes:

1) to not encode the `$setting` and `$protectedSetting` hashtables as Json - my original snippet was using `ConvertTo-Json` on the hashtable to get string json.  In my defence, the documentation for those params indicates: "Specifies private configuration for the extension, **as a string.**".  I will file a documentation bug.

2) (and this I think is the main reason), I updated the `TypeHandlerVersion` to 2.76 which is the current latest version - copy-paste from an Internet example gave me 2.24.  I'm gonna see if I can get away with not specifying the version at all - I would always want the latest.

Comment: TypeHandlerVersion is a mandatory param.  Sigh.  I'll just have to call `Get-AzureRmVMExtensionImage` to dynamically discover the latest version